# IdentityServer4 Update Claim Value from API Project

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I've got a pretty simple simple question I'd appreciate if you can provide a solution.

I have two projects:

- An IdentityServer4 project.
- An API project.

The API project is being protected using IdentityServer4 like the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        options.ApiName = "TestAPI";
        options.ApiSecret = "Password"
    });
```

Up to this point everything is working as expected.

My question is from the API project how can I make update operations on IdentityServer4 like updating a users claim value ?

Comment: Can you also show your ConfigureServices method in your IdentityServer4 Project's Startup class? All the users, claims, ApiResources and clients are configured inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correct - you want to change the claims, inside an API, that is protected by the IDS, that has issued the claims.

In general - this is not possible and not right.

**Why not possible?**

The `ClaimsPrincipal` class, and its `Claims` property is readonly (it has only getter, but no setter):

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Claim> Claims { get; }
```

**Why it is not right?**

Usually the claims are holding some authentication info (roles, username, some user profile information etc). This data is supposed to be issued by the `authentication provider` (in your case the IDS) and it is not supposed to be changed by someone/something, whose authorization depends on this authentication data.

PS: Out of curiosity - what claims exactly do you want to change, or this was just a general question?